# Data reappears after a few seconds when "JSON Remove button" is pressed

Tags: html, webservice-client

I'm currently in the process of creating a HTTP web service that will return data in JSON, XML and String formats. When entering a string and pressing "JSON Search" it will return data back from a database stored in Google SQL. However when I press the "JSON Remove" button next to the "JSON Search" button the data is cleared and then reappears after a few seconds. a br tag between the buttons seems to resolve the issue but messes around with the layout which I don't want to happen.

Code is within the linked image

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/slMIg.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default `type` of a `<button>` is "submit". You have explicitly set your JSON Search button to be a submit button, but technically so is your Remove button. Add the attribute `type="reset"` to have that one be a button that actually clears the form. Or `type="button"` if you just don't want it to do anything except run your event handler.

The problem right now is that you probably have a handler that is clearing the data when you click the Remove button, but since it's an (unintended) submit button, it's also kicking off another query.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Just added type="reset" to the JSON Remove button and that has seemed to have solved my problem :)